# Display month name from a user input of a number between 1 and 12

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a program that lets the user enter a number between 1 and 12 and displays the month name for that month Number.

This is the program I created, but that can't be the easiest, most efficient way to perform that task. Is there an easier way?

```
Dim Month As Integer
Console.WriteLine("Which month is it?")
Month = Console.ReadLine()

Select Case Month
    Case 1
        Console.WriteLine("January")
    Case 2
        Console.WriteLine("February")
    Case 3
        Console.WriteLine("March")
    Case 4
        Console.WriteLine("April")
    Case 5
        Console.WriteLine("May")
    Case 6
        Console.WriteLine("June")
    Case 7
        Console.WriteLine("July")
    Case 8
        Console.WriteLine("August")
    Case 9
        Console.WriteLine("September")
    Case 10
        Console.WriteLine("October")
    Case 11
        Console.WriteLine("November")
    Case 12
        Console.WriteLine("December")
    Case Else
        Console.WriteLine("Error.")
End Select
```

Comment: Welcome. Since you are new I thought I would advise you to take the [tour]. You've now two answers and either should fulfil your request.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Month As Integer
Dim name as string
Console.WriteLine("Which month is it?")
Month = Console.ReadLine()
'check if the month is a number
If Not Integer.TryParse(Month) Then
   console.writeline("Error")
End If
' Set Abbreviate to True to return an abbreviated name or false for full name
name = MonthName(Month, True)
console.writeline("you entered : " & Name)
' name now contains "Apr" or if set to false is "April" (on the assumption of input of 4.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first make use of [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) to ensure the input is in fact an `Integer`.

There are a couple of ways to retrieve the month name from the `Integer` equivalent.

Using [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine("Which month is it?")

Dim monthInput As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), monthInput) Then

    Try
        Console.WriteLine(New DateTime(1, monthInput, 1).ToString("MMMM"))
    Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        Console.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try

End If
```

Using [DateAndTime.MonthName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.monthname(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine("Which month is it?")

Dim monthInput As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), monthInput) Then

    Try
        Console.WriteLine(DateAndTime.MonthName(monthInput))
    Catch ex As ArgumentException
        Console.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try

End If
```

And the one already shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977551/6375113) using [MonthName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxbsw165(v=vs.90).aspx).

You could replace the `Try[...]Catch` code with a simple `If` statment to verify that `monthInput` is in fact a valid month:

```
Console.WriteLine("Which month is it?")

Dim monthInput As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), monthInput) Then

    If monthInput >= 1 AndAlso monthInput <= 12 Then
        'Use one of the following methods:

        'Console.WriteLine(New DateTime(1, monthInput, 1).ToString("MMMM"))
        'Console.WriteLine(DateAndTime.MonthName(monthInput))
        'Console.WriteLine(MonthName(monthInput))
    Else
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} is not a valid month input.", monthInput))
    End If

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you consider easy:

```
Dim month = CInt(Val(Console.ReadLine))

Console.WriteLine(If(month >= 1 AndAlso month <= 12, MonthName(month), "Error."))
```

For culture invariant month names `MonthName(month)` can be replaced with

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month)
```